# $content variable - Is this a reserved variable for a Wordpress function? - php / wordpress

Tags: plugin-development, functions, the-content

I'm just starting to have a dig around in the Wordpress codex because I'm undertaking my first simple plugin.

Can I ask, is the $content variable a reserved variable for the_content() function.  The actual $content variable is all over Wordpress, but I can't seem to find any information on it?  When you search in the codex it just brings up info on the_content()

Any help / pointers on what it does and its usage would be awesome.

Emily.

Answer (score 2):

`$content` - is not reserved in WordPress, it can be used.

In the function `the_content ()` - a variable is used, but it is only available in this function.
The code of the function itself:

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.7/src/wp-includes/post-template.php#L230

Scope of variables in php:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php